# Kendo Tree Icons

Tags: kendo-treeview

How to have two trees on the same page with diff icons:

```
.k-treeview .k-minus {
   background: url('../images/k-minus.png') center center;
}

.k-treeview .k-plus {
   background: url('../images/k-plus.png') center center;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is a little bit unspecified but I'll try to help you.
First off all, to display images in treeView you have to options:

- Sprites - you provide css class for all images you wanna display. All can be in same image file like here: http://demos.kendoui.com/content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png
- Images - you provide url for each image in single file: http://demos.kendoui.com/content/web/treeview/mail.png

Assuming you got two treeViews in you site with diferrent names like `TreeView1` and `TreeView2`. If this treeViews are similar but just need to have different icons, better solution is sprites option, the simplest way is to prepare 2 different images and provide css to display it, like:

```css
#TreeView1 .k-sprite {
    background-image: url("../../content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
}

#TreeView2 .k-sprite {
    background-image: url("../../content/web/treeview/different-sprite.png");
}

.rootfolder { background-position: 0 0; }
.folder { background-position: 0 -16px; }
.pdf { background-position: 0 -32px; }
.html { background-position: 0 -48px; }
.image { background-position: 0 -64px; }
```

Now you can have 2 identical but name treeViews with different icons, eg:

```js
$("#TreeView1").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [{
        text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
            {
                text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                    { text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                    { text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                    { text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }]
});
```

Of course if you prefer images options you just have to describe different url for image in each treeView dataSourve for all items, like that:

```js
$("#TreeView1").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [
        {
            text: "Inbox", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/mail.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Read Mail", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/readmail.png" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Drafts", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/edit.png"
        },
    ]
});

$("#TreeView2").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: [
        {
            text: "Inbox", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/pdf.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Read Mail", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/jpg.png" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Drafts", imageUrl: "../../content/web/treeview/html.png"
        },
    ]
});
```

I based on this kendoUI demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/images. I hope it helps.